# Java application that changes system keyboard languages

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a Java application where I'll have two Jtextfields. The first Jtextfield would supposely change the keyboard input language to japanese (windows keyboard language) where I could write in japanese. The second JTextField would be in english.

I tried finding ways to change the keyboard input in Java (and putting them inside a gained focus event) but none of them were succesfull. For example, I attempted this:

```
JTextField jTextField = ...;
jTextField.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("ja", "JP"));
jTextField.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(Locale.JAPANESE);
```

You guys got any ideas if this is even possible to accomplish? I want this to be an easier alternative to having to switch keyboard languages from Japanese to English every time through the keyboard settings.

Comment: "_I tried finding ways to change the keyboard input in Java (and putting them inside a gained focus event) but none of them were succesfull._" You should include code snippets showing exactly what you attempted so that people do not suggest what you have already tried, or, perhaps even better, can help you figure out if there's a reason why what you've already tried doesn't work.

Comment: jTextField.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("ja", "JP"));
jTextField.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(Locale.JAPANESE);